# Why won't the pipes move?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm  new to python and I'm making a flappy bird game, but the pipes won't move. I made several modules: flappy.py - main module, pipes.py which contains pipe objects, and a player class that has the bird object. Does anyone know solution to my problem?

### main module

```
import pygame
import sys 
from player import Player
from pipes import Pipes
BLUE  = (0,191,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,800))
    flappy = Player(screen)
    pipes = Pipes(screen)
    while True:
     #controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    flappy.moving_up=True
                    flappy.moving_down=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    flappy.moving_up=False
                    flappy.moving_down=True
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        flappy.blitme()
        flappy.moving()
        pipes.draw_upper_pipes()
        pipes.draw_down_pipes(
        pipes.move()
        clock.tick(32) #settings fps to 32
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

### pipes.py module

```
import pygame
import random
class Pipes():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.pipe_x=300
        self.color = (124,252,0) # green
        self.pipe_width=100
        self.pipe_height=random.randrange(100,300)
        self.upperPipe=pygame.Rect(self.pipe_x, 0, self.pipe_width, self.pipe_height) #making upper pipe rect
        self.down_pipe_height = random.randrange(500, 800)
        self.downPipe=pygame.Rect(self.pipe_x, 400, self.pipe_width, self.down_pipe_height) #making bottom pipe rect
    def move(self):
        self.pipe_x-=9
    def draw_upper_pipes(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.upperPipe) #drawing upper pipe
    def draw_down_pipes(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.downPipe) #drawing bottom pipe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use move_ip on your pipe rect

```
def move(self):
    self.pipe_x-=9
    upperPipe.move_ip(pipe_x,pipe_y)
```

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip